# Git don't understand bare true/false (when one is active, remote directory works, when the other one is active local directory works)

Tags: git

If my remote is set to the following, I am able to push from my local branch (and can't push from my remote branch):

```
git config core.bare true
```

If my remote is set to the following, then I can push from remote branch (and can't push from my local branch):

```
to git config core.bare false
```

Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `core.bare = false`, and normally HEAD points to branch `master`, `master` cannot be updated.
That's why push fails.